# Can a shop score 12 on the Joel Test and yet be anything but Agile (or Lean)?

Tags: agile, joel-test, lean

Inspired by [this question - can an agile shop really score 12 on the Joel Test](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58661/can-an-agile-shop-really-score-12-on-the-joel-test): Can you come up with explanations or examples where a software development organization satisfies **technically** all 12 points of the Joel Test, but fails to live up to the agile or lean principles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having an up to date spec is possible with a big design upfront process, one with lots of text and diagrams that are written as a contract. That's hardly agile.

I am tempted to say a quiet team room is also not agile, agile is all about communication, team work, pair programming, collaborating, shared goals. A quiet room might actually mean it's not really a team just a group of peeps in the same room.

A bug database can be considered unnecessary inventory in lean terms.. either fix them or don't.. Piling them up is waste. Having this many bugs that one needs to track them may be indication of a broken process, it's fighting symptoms not the root problem.

Comment: Automated tests are a spec, the very best kind of spec.

Comment: A set of bug cards on the wall is a "bug database"

Comment: "A quiet room might actually mean it's not really a team just a group of peeps in the same room.": Not necessarily. A well-functioning team will reduce communication to the essential and concentrate on getting work done.